# Installation did not not complete successfully. See the IDE log for details - Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to install the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator for Android studio on my mac, but I get the following error shown in the screenshot:
[image: error_screeenshot]

I've looked at similar error descriptions here on SO, but for those error descriptions, it seemed clear from the log that what was wrong was due to an incorrect installation path for Android studio (or something to that extent).

But from what I can tell my error isn't caused by an incorrect path. And installation for other components went just fine. So I'm at a loss at the moment.

Can anyone help me understand what this error points to? Thanks!